# MS-ACCESS: How do you tell if constraints are in place?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I wrote a constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE main
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_main
PRIMARY KEY (x,y,z)
```

The constraint seems to work as I get no errors in syntax or any other indications it didn't work, but I see no indications it did work and don't know how to find the constraint.

1) How do I tell if the constraint was successfully added?

2) How do I properly add a constraint if I am doing this wrong?

Comment: Does Access let you add more than one row with the same x, y, and z values?

Comment: That's an excellent question, didn't really think about it when I tested. I'm looking for the answer now, but we all know Microsoft is notorius for their wonderful documentation and obfiscation techniques. EDIT: It appears they do allow more than one directly in the documentations for SQL Server, but I'm not certain if that's the same for OleDb, which is what I'm using. Which doesn't answer the question as to if Access permits it.

Comment: Found this: **A limitation of the possible values that users can enter into a field. The ANSI SQL DDL CHECK constraint has been added to Microsoft Jet version 4.X when going through the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Jet. The CHECK constraint allows for the creation of business rules that span an entire table or multiple other tables.** Which also doesn't seem to answer my question...

Comment: Primary key constraint != check constraint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE main ADD CONSTRAINT pk_main PRIMARY KEY (x,y,z)"
```

That statement executed without error.  If I was still unsure whether it "worked", I could test by adding a row with values which duplicated the x, y, and z values stored in another row.  If the primary key constraint is effective, the duplicate values would trigger an error.

But it would be quicker to open the table in Design View and examine its indexes.  `DoCmd.OpenTable "main", acViewDesign` ...

[image: Table in Design View displaying indexes]

Alternatively, since the primary key constraint is implemented as an index, and the constraint name is the index name, you could inspect the table's index with DAO.

```vb
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("main").Indexes.Count
 1 
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("main").Indexes(0).Name
pk_main
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("main").Indexes(0).Primary
True
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("main").Indexes(0).Fields.Count
 3 
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("main").Indexes(0).Fields(0).Name
x
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("main").Indexes(0).Fields(1).Name
y
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("main").Indexes(0).Fields(2).Name
z
```

If you want yet another way to check whether the primary key constraint was created, consider the [ADO OpenSchema Method](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186246).  If you're using Dot.Net with OleDb, it provides a similar method.